# TicTacToe Gui in WPF

Tags: c#

So I am in a bit of a situation, I need to have an X or O pop up when I click the buttons but it doesnt want to accept button.Text, button.TextMenu, button.DataContent or button.ContextMenu. What should I do? I was following an old video as well so I don't know if they have changed it.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;
using System.Threading;

namespace ticTacToeGui
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

        }

        public int player = 2;
        public int turns = 0;
        public int s1 = 0;
        public int s2 = 0;
        public int sd = 0;


        private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            Button button = (Button)sender;
            if(player%2==0)
            {
                button.DataContext = "X";
                player++;
                turns++;
            }
            else
            {
                button.DataContext = "O";
                player++;
                turns++;
            }
        }
```

Continues On...

Comment: Did this solution work for you ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use Button's Content Property.

```
   private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Button button = (Button)sender;
        if(player%2==0)
        {
            button.Content = "X";
            player++;
            turns++;
        }
        else
        {
            button.Content= "O";
            player++;
            turns++;
        }
    }
```